# how to import (.dmp) database format in mysql or phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

how to import  (.dmp) database format in mysql or phpmyadmin ?

I am using phpmyadmin mysql tool for database manage. I have receive database backup in .dmp format, I have require import database in phpmyadmin as mysql database format.

Comment: and what have you tried so far

Comment: What does that file contain? I've never heard of that format

Answer (score 5):

you should change the extension manually .dmp to .sql and import using phpmyadmin or mysql as you import .sql files.

for mysql try below code

```
mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {file.sql}
```

replace curly braces with your db details and from phpmyadmin click on import link and browse the file.

Comment: hi ram without extension change allow phpmyadmin import .dmp as oracle database import. you can try this.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a usual dump, only with another file extension?

Answer (score -1):

XAMPP 1.7.7 version phpmyadmin support (.dmp) file import but import format define as (sql,csv,docsql,sml,open document spreadsheet).

you can import .dmp database format.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Does your answer mean that you resolved your problem in any way?